# change a button to a image

Tags: javascript, html

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "hackanm.gif";
}
</script>
```

can you help me to correct the code.
I would like to change the button to a image.
***I would like to use javascript to change html***

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image or style.backgroundImage.

Comment: See updated list of duplicates - there are hundreds

Comment: <button id="myImg" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myImg").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/234273/pexels-photo-234273.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260')";
}
</script>

Comment: Don't forget the quotation mark "url('image...')"